# OpenCL makefile error

Tags: nvidia, compiling, make, opencl, compilation-target

I'm attempting to run a program (openGraphiti), and am running into some errors I can't seem to get past.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/NWWZLdEF) is my full make error, but the relevant part is

```
No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so
```

I've compiled this same program on a different machine, so I know the problem is on my end, and not in the makefile. I know OpenCL is installed correctly, because it passes it the cmake .

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Maybe cmake isn't testing for it? Have you actually looked to see if the file is there? Since you've tagged your question nvidia, do you have the `nvidia-opencl-dev` package installed?

Comment: Yes, I had that installed, I was able to fix it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I fixed this. Turns out the nvidia drivers were not working for whatever reason.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia -*
```

then reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-331-uvm nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-modprobe
```